# Как с помощью Java получить информацию из страницы

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, синтаксический-анализ

Как с помощью Java получить информацию с этой страницы http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/spain/primera-division/rayo-vallecano-valencia-d4LVsDnC/ и других подобных страниц, реализующих Javascript,Ajax? Спасибо!

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, что именно у вас вызывает затруднение и что вы уже реализовали?

Comment: Как это будет применяться? Однократно или на постоянной основе?

Comment: Я могу скачать страницу и отпарсить ее, если это обычный html без использования javascript,ajax. Но если это динамическая страница, то возникают трудности. В примере с этой ссылкой мне нужно скачать и отпарсить таблицу с коэффициентами, но я не могу сделать это с помощью например класса URL, так как эти коэффициенты в явном виде отсутствуют на странице. И да  это будет применяться на постоянной основе. Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: @Дмитрий Вам нужно использовать API этого сайта, другого варианта я не вижу.

Comment: @Sandman Это мне нужно обращаться к службе поддержки сайта? И что вы скажете например о использовании HtmlUnit в этой ситуации? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос конечно не понятен, но как вариант вот простейшая реализация.

```html
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by Железяка on 30.04.2015.
 */
public class IfHtml {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/spain/primera-division/rayo-vallecano-valencia-d4LVsDnC/");

            try {
                LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                String string = reader.readLine();
                while (string != null) {
                    System.out.println(string);
                    string = reader.readLine();
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Суть в том, что мне нужно получить коэффициенты спортивного события из данного сайта, которые обновляются динамически, таблица с этими коэфф.  обрабатывается непосредственно браузером(с применением javascript и ajax) и не видна на странице которую можно достать с помощью кода приведенного вами выше.

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов решить эту проблему несколько:

- автоматизировать настоящий браузер через selenium, открыть желаемую
  страницу в selenium-powered браузере, дать ему выполнить свою работу
  по загрузке страницы и пропарсить нужные данные; далее либо получить
  исходный код страницы через `getPageSource()` и отдать это JSoup на
  парсинг, либо продолжить использовать selenium webdriver API
- инспектировать, как загружается и формируется страница (с помощью
  browser developer tools), если браузер делает дополнительные
  реквесты, повторить их в своем Java коде

Также иногда бывает, что нужные данные уже присутствуют в HTML, но только в другом месте. Например, иногда в script тегах - тоже проверьте это.